# error command \iint already defined

Tags: errors

I constantly receive this message, but I do not use the `amsmath` package.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty, line 645

LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              
                                              
l.645 ...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}
                                              
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

Comment: probably one of the packages you load already loads `amsmath` itself

Comment: mathtools loads amsmath

Comment: @Alex you changed the format of your code when you edited. It's less readable now than it was.

Comment: Also pay attention to conflicts between packages. For instance, you load colortbl after xcolor, which is not allowed according to the xcolor documentation. Instead you should only load xcolor with the table option, like this: \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

Comment: Not sure why you are using `times` and `pxfonts`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I'm begginer in latex, but your tip about put pxfonts after mathtools fix it. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4):

Your preamble is long and a bit confused. Also contradictory: with `\usepackage{times}` it makes little sense to load `pxfonts` that provides Palatino for math (and overrides `times`).

Here's a reorganized version

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

% page format
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

% character set, language and fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % better than pxfonts
\usepackage{textcomp}

% spacing and general setup
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

% math
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath
%\usepackage{gensymb} % probably not necessary
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{cancel}

% general tools
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfigure}% obsolete!
\usepackage{enumerate} % perhaps better enumitem
\usepackage{multicol}

% graphics
\usepackage{tikz}

% tables
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

If you decide to load `pxfonts` notwithstanding its shortcomings, then you need to move the “math” section in front of the “fonts” section.

Be aware that `subfigure` has been obsolete for a long time. Either load `subfig` (which has a slightly different syntax, but mainly `\subfigure` and `\subtable` are replaced by the generic `\subfloat`) or the recommended `subcaption` package.

In any case, try and see what packages you are *really* using and remove the calls to those that aren't needed.

Comment: thank you so much! I´ve been learning a lot with your comment. In deed, some packages are really confuse to me yet. I´ve been working in my report´s lab with stack support. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order of packages may help you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

Here, I've kept `pxfonts` after `mathtools` will solve it...